# RoR: def to_s for two names/labels

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I am using def to_s to change the numerical value of a user in to the string.

A user has a first name and a surname though - f_name and s_name.

In my model:

```
def to_s
f_name
end
```

Works fine. But how can I get the surname alongside?? Thx

Comment: Does a user always have both, a first name and a surname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is possible that you have only a first or last name, then consider:

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].compact.join(' ')
end

def to_s
  full_name
end
```

Whatever technique you use, I would recommend that you create a method to express the full name, and then reference that in the to_s method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interpolation:

```
def to_s
  "#{f_name} {l_name}" # or f_name + ' ' + l_name
end
```

Comment: I prefer the version that uses string interpolation, because version that concatenates the string with `+` fails when `f_name` is `nil`.

Comment: @spickermann for me string interpolation always looked better, so +1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version is to just return a string concatenating both name parts:

```
def to_s
  "#{f_name} #{s_name}"
end
```

In Ruby, the last value in a method is the implied return value. There are more explicit ways to do this, and other ways to concatenate strings. You could do this as well:

```
def to_s
  return f_name + ' ' + s_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks both! Both approaches work. Thanks very much :) Can't tick for a few minutes!